# A really complicated question on newtonian (classical) mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> A particle is moving along the positive $y$-direction with a velocity $v_1$. A belt is placed in front of it which is moving in the positive $x$-direction with a velocity $v_2$.

If the co-efficient of friction between the belt and the particle is say $z$ and the point where the belt and the particle collide is taken as the origin, then find the point where the relative sliding between them stops, given the mass of the particle is $m$. (We have to find the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates with respect the origin). 
The way i understand the question is that the friction acts in the backward direction and provides negative acceleration. So we have to integrate it using the relation $a$ = $vdv/dx$ where $dv/dx$ refers to the slope of velocity and acceleration in the velocity displacement graph.Problem is what are the integration limits.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Use a frame of reference in which the belt is stationary.

Comment: very sorry but i have posted in multiple sites with no luck, my friend recommended this site to me. As to Mr. Sammy gerbil, I did do that but i have trouble as to finding the direction of friction,I assumed it to be acting in the direction opposite to that of the relative velocity vector.But i had trouble integrating(I don't know the limits).